# set a delegate class as Key in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a NSMutableDictionary that has the Keys made up of UIViewController delegates, like this:

```
-(void) registerAsLocationManagerDelegate:(id<RTALocationManagerDelegate>)lmDelegate forPeriodicUpdates:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
{
    NSTimer* periodicTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(runPeriodicUpdates:) 
                                                            userInfo:nil 
                                                             repeats:YES];
    [periodicUpdateDelegates setObject:periodicTimer forKey:lmDelegate];
}
```

However, my code crashes because with this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RTALocationsListViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9750'

Any way around it? Am I doing something completely wrong by trying this? Should I approach this differently? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In general, you should use ‘standard’ classes for key objects whenever possible. If you want to use your custom classes, they need to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol (implement `-copyWithZone:`), you need to make sure that two objects that are the same in `-isEqual:` also return the same value for `-hash`, and you need to make sure that `-hash` doesn’t change whilst the object is in the dictionary even if the object internal state changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) keys can be any object as long as they conform to the [`NSCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

The error you are getting is because it `copyWithZone` is part of this protocol, and it may not be implemented by your delegate object. - So it can't be a key.

Your choices are to get the string representation of your class and use that as a key - but this might not work if you have multiple delegates that are of the same class (because then the keys would not be unique). Or, implement the `NSCopying` protocol in your delegate classes.

Comment: -1. Copying a delegate doesn't make much sense. Using the class name doesn't make much sense either, and using the delegate's description (which should be somewhat unique because it includes the address of the class) is dubious. The easiest reliable way is to use `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:lmDelegate]` as a key.

Answer (score 0):

While NSDictionary copies keys, the CFDictionary functions do not. Use CFDictionary instead (or take advantage of "toll-free bridging").

Comment: "the CFDictionary functions do not" That's not entirely true. CFDictionary allows you to specify the semantics. So you *could* have it copy keys (e.g. `kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks`), or you could have it retain them, or not retain them at all. It's flexible.

Comment: @user102008: Last I checked, `-[NSMutableDictionary setValue:forKey:]` did an explicit copy, while `CFDictionarySetValue()` did not. This might mean if you create a key-copying `CFDictionary` and toll-free bridge it to `NSMutableDictionary`, keys end up getting copied twice.